# Rails: eager loading a belongs_to with :conditions refering to self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, belongs-to

In my model there are parents, children and named groups of children. Groups belong to parents, children belong to parents, and children may belong to a group of the same parent.

Groups may be deleted and later recreated with the same name but a different id. A child refers to its group by name, not id, so that it will belong to the same group if the group is ever recreated. A group with the same name may exist in multiple parents, so we need to distinguish between them.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :children
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  has_many :children,
    :foreign_key => :group_name,
    :primary_key => :name,
    :conditions => proc { "children.parent_id = #{self.parent_id}" }
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  belongs_to :group,
    :foreign_key => :group_name,
    :primary_key => :name,
    :conditions => proc { "groups.parent_id = #{self.parent_id}" }
end
```

This works wonderfully until I try to eagerly load the groups of children. `Child.where(...).includes(:group)` gives `undefined method parent_id' for #<Class:0x00000002dcc290>`. The `self` in the conditions proc is the class Child, not a Child object.

How do I eager load such an association? Or is my model structure just stupid? Composite primary keys for the groups have crossed by mind, but I'd rather not since rails doesn't support that by default.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the :finder_sql option will work for the has_many relationship. Unfortunately, it's not an option for the belongs_to relationship.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  has_many :children,
    :foreign_key => :group_name,
    :primary_key => :name,
    :finder_sql => proc { "select distinct children.id from children where children.parent_id = #{self.parent_id}" }
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry :( Rails (eager-)loads the groups with a separate 'SELECT ... FROM groups WHERE name IN (...) AND whatever-is-in-:conditions'. The query doesn't refer to the children table.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, looks like the :finder_sql option will do what you want. I'm going to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't work either. The belongs_to in Child doesn't use the finder_sql, and according to the docs you can't use :finder_sql with belongs_to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coding manually approximately what Rails does when eager-loading:

```
class Child
  def self.eager_load_groups(children)
    keys = children.map {|c|
      "(#{connection.quote(c.parent_id)}, #{connection.quote(c.group_name)})"
    }
    keys.uniq!
    return if keys.empty?

    groups = Group.where('(parent_id, name) IN (' + keys.join(',') + ')')
    groups_by_key = Hash[groups.map {|g| [[g.parent_id, g.name], g] }]

    for c in children
      c.group = groups_by_key[[c.parent_id, c.group_name]]
    end
  end
end
```